# mongoose auto completion not work in vscode

Tags: mongodb, visual-studio-code, mongoose, autocomplete

I cant get mongoose auto completion in my IDE,

I have tried restarting my IDE and work file and updating linux packages (including vscode) and restart my system but that didnt help.

you can see my problem in one picture:
[image]

&

[image]

I have tried in another places like codesandbox :

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/busy-chaplygin-qym7pp?file=/index.js:5,5

go to above link and just hit ctrl + space and then you wont see auto completion:
[image]

since i started learning mongodb using mongoose i have this issue, whats the problem? how can i fix this?

my system and vscode info:

[image]

```
$lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solved it by adding a new keyword before `mongoose.Schema`, like this:

[image]

special thanks to https://t.me/deptyped

Answer (score 0):

Write `new mongoose.Schema()` instead of `mongoose.Schema()`

Answer (score 0):

if any of the other answers don't work for you, you're probably using an old version of mongoose (eg.  "mongoose": "^5.10.7"). Please upgrade the latest version ("mongoose": "^8.2.2" as of this answer) and it should work for you.